# Raising handlebars using a stem raiser on B'twin Triban 500

Tags: handlebars, stem, adjustment

I've just got a second hand B'twin Triban 500. The seat goes easily high enough, but I've not used a road bike before and the handlebars are far too low for me, even with all the spacers in place. I understand that the bike has a carbon fork. I'm looking at getting a stem raiser so that I can increase the handlebar height to a more comfortable level while I get used to the bike, and saw [this one](https://www.evanscycles.com/fwe-stem-riser-1-1-8-EV180192) on Evans cycles, but it says not to be used for a carbon steering fork; does this mean I could not use it on my bike, and why so?

Similarly, I saw [this one](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Handlebar-stem-raiser-fits-steerers/dp/B0039Z6ANO/ref=sr_1_5?keywords=bike%20stem%20raiser&qid=1559383540&s=gateway&sr=8-5) too; it doesn't mention not being used with a carbon fork, but should I assume that given the previous one?

Thanks!

EDIT: Turns out that a carbon fork doesn't mean a carbon steerer tube; thanks for those who commented! Any general tips regarding the situation are welcomed :)

Comment: The Evans one says it should not be used with “carbon steerer tubes”. These are often found on more expensive fork models. Many carbon forks have aluminium steerer tubes, so find out which yours has first

Comment: The Triban 500 is an entry-level aluminium bike with carbon forks, so I'd be very surprised if it had a carbon steerer tube. But you should check.

Comment: Road bikes are definitely lower at the front than a MTB.   Could it partially be an acclimatisation to the road position ?

Comment: Got a photo of your stem and bars? And how long is the stem? You might be able to use a different length or have it angled up, to get a couple centimetres better fit.

Comment: If the bike is similar to the current model, it appears to come with a (fairly road-bike standard) -8° stem.  Just flipping it should add at least 1cm, or more for a longer stem.  (Warning though, the road stem currently on sale on the Decathlon site is non-reversible so I'm not going to guarantee you can do this with your current stem.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in comments a steerer tube extender should not be user with a carbon fiber composite steerer tube. Less expensive CFC forks often have an aluminum steerer tube.

You may want to consider a stem with a greater angle that will give more handle bar rise before a steerer tube extender, that would be a stronger option.

Are you riding with hands on the drops of the bars, or on the higher brake hoods position? Most riders spend most of their time on the hoods. If you are riding on the  drops and that feels too low, try riding on the hoods.

[image]

Comment: @DavidW Yes, fixed.